# Program isn't asking the user for input

Tags: r

I tried everything, but my program isn't asking the user to input the number, I'm a beginner in R, Please help.

```
foo <- function(){
number<-readline(prompt="Enter any number: " )
number<-as.integer(number)
return(number)
}

print(paste(foo()))
```

Comment: It didn't asking the user to give input

Comment: Works fine here...

Comment: But it is not working for me, It directly print NA in output

Comment: I'm using R online compiler to test this program

Comment: Try locally, online compiler might have the keyboard input disabled.

Comment: I tried with Many online compilers, but same problem,

Answer (score 1):

```
foo <- function(){
cat("Enter any number: ")
number <- readLines("stdin",n=1)
number <- as.integer(number)
return(number)
}

print(paste(foo()))
```

its working here https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-r-online/

Comment: Which "online compiler" did you test this on? It doesn't work at https://rdrr.io/snippets/

Comment: its working here https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-r-online/ , turn on the interactive mode

Comment: Great, add that link to your post.